# Uncaught TypeError: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a code and am getting the following exception in bootstrap for jQuery 2.1.4

```
Uncaught TypeError: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.
    jQueryDetection util.js:179
    <anonymous> util.js:195
    <anonymous> bootstrap.min.js:6
    <anonymous> bootstrap.min.js:6
```

and the code of my html file is as follows

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
     <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>****</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///C:/Users/Senjuti Bhattacharya/coursera-test/lecture3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///C:/Users/Senjuti Bhattacharya/coursera-test/lecture3/css/styles.css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oxygen:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
     </head>
    <body>
     <header>
       <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
         <div class="container">
    
         </div>
       </nav>
    
    
     </header>
      
   

<!-- jQuery (Bootstrap JS plugins depend on it) -->
   <script src="file:///C:/Users/Senjuti Bhattacharya/coursera-test/lecture3/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
   <script src="file:///C:/Users/Senjuti Bhattacharya/coursera-test/lecture3/js/bootstrap.min.js">

</script>
       <script src="file:///C:/Users/Senjuti Bhattacharya/coursera-test/lecture3/js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: **Danger**: That version of jQuery has [known security problems](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-6538/product_id-11031/version_id-286389/Jquery-Jquery-2.1.4.html) and is no longer supported. Upgrade to a current version of jQuery.

Comment: Odds are you just got the the path to jQuery wrong.

Comment: well which one do I install, your suggestion?

Comment: The *current* version.

Answer (score 0):

you've already included **JQuery** before **bootstrap.js**, seems there is a problem in your path.

Answer (score -1):

Include all Javascript src in <head> section.

Comment: That won't help and is generally considered to be the opposite of best practises.